# Can "has been" be copular? Can the perfect tenses be copular?

Tags: syntax, english, parts-of-speech, copula

Do any or all of these conjugations of 'be' count as copulae?

> I have been a plumber

> I could have been a plumber

> I have been startled

I think they might not be, because they aren't really expressions of current identity of the subject, and in the last case because the "subject complement" would appear to be a verb.

Comment: _Be_ is always an auxiliary verb. If this makes it "copular", it will do so in any tense and construction.

Comment: The last example is ambiguous. It can either be a copular _be_ in the perfect, or it can be (non-copular) _startle_ in the perfect passive. Only context can disambiguate between the two: “I have been startled for several hours now, and my eyebrows are starting to hurt” is copular (_startled_ is an adjective), while “I have been startled by my brother three times today already – next time, I’m punching him!” is non-copular (_startled_ is a participle, part of the VP _have been startled_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if it is a copula in the simple present, it is also a copula in any conjugation available. Adding tense, aspect and mood to a copula does not change its functional role.